# Android - How do I keep a button clicked (Selected)?

Tags: java, android, button, textview, calculator

I am trying to build a calculator with two TextView fields for the two numbers. I figured out how to input the numbers using an "in-app" number pad for the top number, Operand 1 [textView] (I know it would be easier using an EditText but this is for an assignment). I am having trouble switching to the second textView, Operand 2 [textView2].

When I am done input the number for textView, I want to switch to textView2 (using the plus, minus, mult, and/or div Buttons) and continue to enter in the numbers so I can use it for calculations.

Here is an Image of what my app looks like. Please ignore the stars, progress bar, and raido buttons as they are apart of the assignment but not relevent to the calculator. [image]

Do you have any suggestion about how I can do this?

> Android Code

```
package com.example.tristan.assn2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    String operand1 = "";
    String operand2 = "";
    String oneS = "1";
    String twoS = "2";
    String threeS = "3";
    String fourS = "4";
    String fiveS = "5";
    String sixS = "6";
    String sevenS = "7";
    String eightS = "8";
    String nineS = "9";
    String zeroS = "0";
    String dotS = ".";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view)
    {
        Button clickedButton = (Button) view;


        Button one =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button two =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button three =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button four =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button five =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        Button six =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        Button seven =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        Button eight =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        Button nine =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        Button zero =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);

        Button dot =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
        Button clear =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);

        Button plus =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button17);
        Button minus =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button15);
        Button mult =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button19);
        Button div =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button21);
        Button sr =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button16);
        Button fac =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button20);
        Button dd =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button22);

        Button equal =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button23);

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


            //OPERAND1
        if(clickedButton == minus) {
            operand1 = "-";
            list1.add(operand1);
        }

            if (clickedButton == one) {
                operand1 = oneS;
                list1.add(operand1);
            }
            if (clickedButton == two) {
                operand1 = twoS;
                list1.add(operand1);
            }
            if (clickedButton == three) {
                operand1 = threeS;
                list1.add(operand1);
            }
            if (clickedButton == four) {
                operand1 = fourS;
                list1.add(operand1);
            }
            if (clickedButton == five) {
                operand1 = fiveS;
                list1.add(operand1);
            }
            if (clickedButton == six) {
                operand1 = sixS;
                list1.add(operand1);
            }
            if (clickedButton == seven) {
                operand1 = sevenS;
                list1.add(operand1);
            }
            if (clickedButton == eight) {
                operand1 = eightS;
                list1.add(operand1);
            }
            if (clickedButton == nine) {
                operand1 = nineS;
                list1.add(operand1);
            }
            if (clickedButton == zero) {
                operand1 = zeroS;
                list1.add(operand1);
            }
            if (clickedButton == dot) {
                operand1 = dotS;
                list1.add(operand1);
            }
            //Builds String from ArrayList
            StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
            for (String s1 : list1) {
                sb1.append(s1);
            }
            //STRING NUMBER
            String output1 = sb1.toString();
            textView.setText(output1);

        //NEED TO CONVERT TO DOUBLE*****************





        //IF plus, minus, mult, div is pressed, switch to Operand 2 and input numbers

        if(clickedButton == plus || clickedButton == minus || clickedButton == mult || clickedButton == div) {


            if (clickedButton == one) {
                operand2 = oneS;
                list2.add(operand2);
            }
            if (clickedButton == two) {
                operand2 = twoS;
                list2.add(operand2);
            }
            if (clickedButton == three) {
                operand2 = threeS;
                list2.add(operand2);
            }
            if (clickedButton == four) {
                operand2 = fourS;
                list2.add(operand2);
            }
            if (clickedButton == five) {
                operand2 = fiveS;
                list2.add(operand2);
            }
            if (clickedButton == six) {
                operand2 = sixS;
                list2.add(operand2);
            }
            if (clickedButton == seven) {
                operand2 = sevenS;
                list2.add(operand2);
            }
            if (clickedButton == eight) {
                operand2 = eightS;
                list2.add(operand2);
            }
            if (clickedButton == nine) {
                operand2 = nineS;
                list2.add(operand2);
            }
            if (clickedButton == zero) {
                operand2 = zeroS;
                list2.add(operand2);
            }
            if (clickedButton == dot) {
                operand2 = dotS;
                list2.add(operand2);
            }
            //Builds String from ArrayList
            StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
            for (String s2 : list2) {
                sb2.append(s2);
            }
            //STRING NUMBER
            String output2 = sb2.toString();
            textView2.setText(output2);
        }
    }
}
```

> XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.tristan.assn2.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="/"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button21"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button18"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button18"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button18"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button15"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

    <Button
        android:text="3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

    <Button
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

    <Button
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

    <Button
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button11"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

    <Button
        android:text="5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

    <Button
        android:text="6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

    <Button
        android:text="7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button4"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

    <Button
        android:text="8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

    <Button
        android:text="9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

    <Button
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

    <Button
        android:text="."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="87dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="87dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

    <Button
        android:text="-"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

    <Button
        android:text="+"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button17"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_marginRight="47dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="47dp"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />

    <Button
        android:text="x"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button18"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button17"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button17"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button17"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

    <Button
        android:text="x"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button19"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button17"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button17"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button17"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

    <Button
        android:text="sr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button16"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button20"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button20"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

    <Button
        android:text="!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button20"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button21"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button21"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button21"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

    <Button
        android:text="DD - DMS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        android:id="@+id/button22"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button20"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button20"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

    <TextView
        android:hint="Operand 1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button5" />

    <TextView
        android:hint="Operand 2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button8" />

    <TextView
        android:hint="Results"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />

    <RatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:isIndicator="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:text="Use for Operand 1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button23"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:text="Use for Operand 2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioButton"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2" />

    <Button
        android:text="="
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button23"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="C"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button8"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show me the outputs which you got

Comment: @KiranBennyJoseph As you can see, I can only input numbers into first textView but when I hit the plus, minus, mult, div buttons, it wont switch to textView2 -- https://i.gyazo.com/c373326faf64ef2019d9521b52cd4b57.png

Comment: Why do you have two TextViews? Every calculator app I have used has a single view where either it displays the entire operation or just number currently being typed.

Comment: Does your calculator have an = button?

Comment: Suggestion: Read about GridLayout. I think you can use this to create a cleaner XML file.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice There are two textViews because that is what my assignment calls for. the equals button is at the top right.

Comment: Is the user allowed to operate on more than two numbers, for example adding 3 numbers together, before pressing =?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes. When the numbers are entered they go into an ArrayList

Comment: @Tristan use switch

Comment: @KiranBennyJoseph Please elaborate on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this :

```
public class YourActivityName extends AppCompatActivity {


TextView operand1, operand2,result,tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dd);

    operand1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    operand2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    result= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tv=operand1;
}


public void sendMessage(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.button19 || v.getId() == R.id.button15 || v.getId() == R.id.button17 || v.getId() == R.id.button21 || v.getId() == R.id.button18) {
        tv=operand2;
    }

    if(v.getId()==R.id.button7){
        tv.setText(tv.getText()+"7");
    }

    if(v.getId()==R.id.button8){
        tv.setText(tv.getText()+"8");
    }

    if(v.getId()==R.id.button23){
        int op1=Integer.parseInt(operand1.getText().toString());
        int op2=Integer.parseInt(operand2.getText().toString());
        op2+=op1;
        result.setText(op2+"");
        tv=operand1;
        operand1.setText("");
        operand2.setText("");
    }

}
```

}

this is code only for having addition on pressing  '=' button and for taking input only from button '7' and '8' you need to and functionality for other buttons and operations ..but it should solve your problem of changing textview for input...

you can also do by means of flags . as suggested by @Code-Apprentice ...

Comment: This helps a lot and is a lot less complicated than what I was trying to do. When I click the = button is there a way to distinguish which operation i want to perform? Instead of plus I want to do mult. Do I somehow use "if" statements?

Comment: you can set flag for each operation separately or can define a single variable and set it accordingly  as user click button for operations (+,-,etc)...and on pressing "=" button use can use if statement and check flags or value for variable and do operation acoordingly..

Answer (score 2):

You have to listen the key clicks after the plus/minus/.. button clicks occurs. Use a flag. set the flag 1 when plus/minus/.. or textview2 gets clicked and change the textview to textview2 and list1 to list2. Do the vice versa when textview1 is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You should toggle a boolean flag whenever the user clicks an operator button. Then when the user clicks a number button, check this flag to determine which operand is being used.

In conjunction with this flag, you can also have a variable like `TextView currentTextView` which is assigned to refer to the currently used TextView. Then whenever the user clicks an operator button, assign this variable to the other TextView. This strategy will make it so you only need `if` statements in the `OnClickListener`s for the operator buttons. You won't need any `if` statements in the `OnClickListener`s for the number buttons.

p.s. Note that every number button already displays the numerical character. You can use this fact to remove nearly all of the `if...else` chain in your click listener.

p.p.s. You should consider writing different `OnClickListener`s for each button. With the previously mentioned strategy, you can have a single listener for all the number buttons, but I still suggest creating a different listener for each operator button.

Comment: I have never heard of the term "flag" before. is it just an "if" statement? If(clickedButton == plus) { boolean p = true;}

Comment: @Tristan Yes, a flag is typically a boolean variable. You can also use an `int` or `enum` if there are more than two possible states. In order to be useful, the flag needs to be declared outside of the `if` statement, most likely as a field.